Aws Connect tag resources not appearing in Cost Explorer
I am working with AWS Connect a lot and i wanted to tag some resources like the phoneNumber. I already tagged it and also activated that tag in aws cost allocation tags.
The problem is that after 3 days that tag is not appearing in the tag filter neither for GroupBy By Dimension or as a Filter.
I already tried changing the Date range or granularity. I also enabled the cost by resources. And the phoneNumber is generating cost daily.
I really don't know what else to do and i really need this feature.
I am the root account btw
